# Is there a population limit in Anno 1602?

Tags: anno-1602

I'm playing a scenario which consists of a lot of very large islands which allowed me to get the population above 20000. However, if I build new pioneers, their number is 0 (which can't be because there's always at least one per house) and the taxes as well. They complain about a missing marketplace although they're covered by more than one and don't develop. If I destroy one aristocrat one settler develops (up to an aristocrat) and if I build a pioneer at the location where I removed the aristocrat he remains in the described state.

Answer (score 1):

When your city reaches a population of >10000* inhabitants on one island**, the game starts freaking out. Technically there is no limit to the amount of citizens you can get, the game just can't handle it. I know, it sucks :(

*This is roughly the number of inhabitants were the game goes weird for me, I don't know the exact value and whether it is consistent or not.

**20000 inhabitants spread out over several different islands shouldn't cause any problems.

P.S. Awesome to hear people are still playing Anno 1602 :D